# GAE/P: Serve file directly from GCS to user without reading into GAE memory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In my App Engine app, I'm using the [GCS Python Client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) to store some files.

Currently, to serve the files to a user, I do the following:

1. Read the file from GCS to App Engine using the GCS Python client library
2. Serve the file to the user using webapp2 (`self.response.write(...)`)

It seems that there should be a way to serve this file directly to a user.

I don't want to modify ACLs because the file needs to remain private, but it would be nice to not have to read the file into GAE memory in order to serve it to the user.

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a signed URL, then send the signed URL to the client. The client can then use the signed URL to download the data direct from GCS. You can set an expiry on the URL so that it only works for the period of time that is acceptable to your application.

More information in the docs -> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs

And here's some example python code -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python

Comment: Thanks!  Google should add that functionality to the GCS client library.